# get input path to submit to dropbox in php

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, dropbox

I have the following;

```
$FilePath = "c:\user\test\koala.jpg";

$put = $dropbox->putFile($FilePath);
```

or

```
$put = $dropbox->putFile("c:\user\test\koala.jpg");
```

This works great, and uploads the file to dropbox.

However, obviously I can not get the full path ie `c:\user\test\koala.jpg` through a form input box, due to security restrictions.

Is there a way around this that would work. Where I can just get `$FilePath` through some form of input without having to submit it as a temp file to my server.

I have put the full code below.

```
<?php

// @link https://github.com/BenTheDesigner/Dropbox/blob/master/Dropbox/API.php#L122-139

// Require the bootstrap
require_once('bootstrap.php');

// Extend your sript execution time where required
set_time_limit(0);

$put = $dropbox->putFile($FilePath);

// Dump the output
// var_dump($chunked);
```

Comment: Why is there a problem creating a temp file on your server? That's how normally all file uploads work anyways.

Comment: Well I want it to go to straight to dropbox, and not my own server. I will be sending it to two places if I sent to my own server. And some of these files will be very large.

Comment: Then I can suggest you some JS method maybe. As you know, PHP will always work only on server-side.

Comment: Yes I was thinking of javascript, but the full path can not be used. Will only give the filename, but not the full path.

Comment: True. Well, if dropbox doesn't have it's own script for puproses like that, I would say that the only possibility is to upload the file to your server and then send it to dropbox.

Comment: You see. If you have a file on your server, you can upload it from your server to dropbox. If the file is on the client, you can't. At least not with PHP, because PHP has no access to the client. You have to use something else on the client side or upload the file to your server and then upload it from the server to dropbox. I see no other solution.

Comment: That is what I wanted to avoid really. Was wondering if there was possibly some html5 solution. Seems so simple yet I have a feeling could get overly complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Test something like this:

**HTML**

```
...
<form type="POST" action="myPhpUploadPage.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="file"/><br/>
   <input type="submit" value="send"/>
</form>
...
```

**PHP (myPhpUploadPage.php)**

```
// Require the bootstrap
require_once('bootstrap.php');

// Extend your sript execution time where required
set_time_limit(0);

if(isset($_FILES['file'])){
  $FilePay = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
  $put = $dropbox->putFile($FilePath);
} else {
  echo 'not file selected';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about uploading your files to your server, and after running the script to copy them to your Dropbox account. Then run a script to erase the files in the temporary directory or specific folder.